# How to pass a java.util.Date in URL from JSF page?

Tags: jsf, url, parameter-passing, jsf-2.2

I need to pass a java.util.Date in URL from a backing bean to another Facelet (and bean).

Can anybody tell me if this is somehow possible? I know I can't pass complex objects in URL, but does this include Date too?

Or do I have to convert my inserted date (using JSF tag `<h:inputText>`) to a String, pass it in URL and then convert it back to date?

Comment: *As a side note*: the part of URL that contains data to be passed is called a [**query string**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fact: HTTP request parameters are of `String` type.

So, logically, you've got to convert from `Date` to `String` while preparing and writing the HTTP request parameter before sending and convert from `String` back to `Date` while reading and parsing the incoming HTTP request parameter.

You're not clear as to how exactly you're preparing the URL, but given that you're obtaining the `Date` as input by `<h:inputText>`, I'll assume that you're trying to pass it as a parameter of a redirect URL in a backing bean action method. In that case, use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert from `Date` to `String`.

```
public String submit() {
    String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(date);
    return "newpage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&date=" + dateString;
}
```

In the receiving page, `newpage.xhtml`, you can use `<f:viewParam>` to set it as a bean property. It uses `SimpleDateFormat` under the covers, so you can use the same pattern syntax.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="date" value="#{bean.date}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyyMMddHHmmss" />
    </f:viewParam>
</f:metadata>
```

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)

Comment: Yes I got the date as util.Date from JSF inputText and converted it first to String and than back to Date for database queries. But the tip with the DateTime converter for viewParams is good. Thank you!